# Alternatives to Reflection

Tags: java, serialization, reflection

I would like to implement my own [Universal Binary JSON Specification](http://ubjson.org)-like specification. As one of my first steps I would like to have a method, which takes an object as parameter, like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) does in its `String com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Object src)` method. So I would like to know the fields and the data types of them. As far as I know does Gson use reflection to achieve that.

Another "solution" could be Serialization. But it's maybe tough to extract the fields from there, and I would prefer anyway, that it's not a must for the object to implement `Serializable`.

Is Reflection the way to go with my intentions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider bean introspection (see java.beans.Introspector) for a cleaner, albeit more limited approach.

If your objects are not pure beans (i.e. you need to map fields without getters or setters), you need to use reflection.

Comment: That looks very promising. Especially the ´getBeanInfo(Class<?> beanClass)´ method sounds very good. The need of getters and setters should be no problem.